# Boxplot - finding values for lower and upper whisker

Tags: r, boxplot

I need to find the exact value of each horizontal line (The small horizontal dash
above the box is the largest observation that is less than or equal to the 3rd
quartile plus 1.5 * r. The small horizontal dash below the box is the smallest
observation that is greater than or equal to the 1st quartile minus 1.5 *r) of each box.

I tried with the formula `(Q3+1.5*(Q3-Q1))` and `Q1-1.5*(Q3-Q1)` but in some cases it fails.

I tried with `boxplot$conf` but it failed with me.

Comment: if you do : mybox<-boxplot(...) and then mybox$stats, you should have the values you're looking for (check ?boxplot for more informations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access these values in the following way.

```
boxplot(dat)$stats[c(1, 5), ]
```

where `dat` is your data.

Comment: Very helpful   ..... thanks